# Different data in different HTML table columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got 2 sets of data (arrays), 5 records for each array that I want to show in 2 corresponding columns (on a view).

I can't seem to get 2 separate bits of data in the same table:

```
@data_a
@data_b

@data_a | @data_b
-----------------
  a(1)  |   b(1) 
  a(2)  |   b(2)
  a(3)  |   b(3)
  a(4)  |   b(4)
  a(5)  |   b(5)
```

Comment: What do you mean with table?, what kind of table?

Comment: Sorry; should have been clearer.  I mean a table in a view (<table> </table>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use [`Array#zip`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) to merge both variables (being array) and get a main one, containing each pair of values, this way you can iterate and get first and second value, add them within the needed html structure and print them as you need:

```
<% @data_a = %w[a(1) a(2) a(3) a(4) a(5)] %>
<% @data_b = %w[b(1) b(2) b(3) b(4) b(5)] %>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>@data_a</th>
      <th>@data_b</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @data_a.zip(@data_b).each do |a, b| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= a %></td>
        <td><%= b %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```